# How to implement geofencing for iOS 9?

Tags: ios, ios9, geofencing

I need geofencing capability for my iOS 9 app. What API providers provides geofencing capability? I checked Foursquare and they don't seem to provide this.  [Geoloqi](http://geoloqi.com) just got acquired and that option seems to be out of question as well.

If no third party option is available, how does one go about implementing geofencing for iOS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

iOS has the ability to geofence without the need for a third party API. Core location should have everything you need. Check out this tutorial to learn more.

[Geofencing Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/95014/geofencing-ios-swift)